# How to run a git command from a pipeline using yaml in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I simply want to run a Git command from a YAML file. Here's what I have in my YAML file:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git config user.name "my_name"
      git config user.password "my_password"
      git clone https://my_repo@dev.azure.com/the_repo_stuff
      git checkout dev
      git checkout -b newer-branch
      git commit -a -m 'new branch commit'
      git push --set-upstream origin newer-branch
```

I'm getting `fatal: could not read Password for 'https://my_repo@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled`

The password I used is what I generated in Azure DevOps in the Clone window.

For now, my goal is simply to get this script to create a branch. Eventually, I would like to pass in variables and make it more complex.

Comment: Can you specify if the repository which you want to checkout is the same in which pipeline.yaml is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clicking the "**Generate Git Credentials**" option when cloning Azure repos, you will see below panel.

[image]

Thus you could create a branch for this repository using following script

```
git clone https://username:password@dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/repository_name
cd repository_name
git checkout dev
git checkout -b newer-branch
git commit -a -m 'new branch commit'
git push --set-upstream origin newer-branch
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. 

For others finding this answer, don't forget to set permissions in Project Settings > Repositories > Permissions

Comment: So, I'm glad this worked for you, and I don't doubt that it did work for you, but I'm a little confused as to *why* it's needed - the combination of `checkout:self` and `persistCredentials:true` has worked for me to allow scripts access to Git with additional steps?

Answer (score 7):

I am a little bit confused why you need such thing.

In case of using the same repository in which pipeline.yaml is located you should be able to use git commands because of

```yaml
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

In case you want to checkout different repository, consider checking it out with **service connection** and **multiple repositories** option:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository
- script: |
     git checkout -b new-branch
     git push --set-upstream origin newer-branch

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Source: [Multiple repositories documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

Also keep in mind that multiple repositories will change default repositories path:

> If you are using default paths, adding a second repository checkout step changes the default path of the code for the first repository. For example, the code for a repository named tools would be checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s when tools is the only repository, but if a second repository is added, tools would then be checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s\tools. If you have any steps that depend on the source code being in the original location, those steps must be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SSH? If you are, then I think you will have to create an SSH Key Authentication in order to clone to your server. For more info, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops