# How to use symlink in Azure dev-ops?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a app repo that contains all of our app code. We also have a `library' repo that houses styling (tailwind) and simple button elements that we use in multiple projects. On my local system I create a symlink between the 2 folders to generate a Nuxt build.

How would I achieve this on a pipeline or a release pipeline in Azure dev-ops? I'm think I need 2 pipelines.

1. App
2. Library

And then in the release pipeline create 2 artifacts, one for both. Then during the release I can make a step that creates a symlink between the 2 artifacts so I can complete the `Nuxt generate`.

The goal is to run a Cypress e2e test in the release pipeline, but for that I need a build. And for the build I need both repos.

Is this the right approach or is there a easier/different way?

Comment: I would rather use [Publish and consume artifacts in azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) than creating a symlink.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up publishing the artifacts and just download the lib artifact in the app folder :) that way no symlink was needed.

Comment: Please keep in mind that if `lib build` pipeline is deleted, the published `pipeline artifacts` for that will also be deleted. You could also consider checking out the `lib` repo locally in current workspace and then proceed with generating the artifacts and sym-linking(or using the local paths), to generate the final artifact. While checking out any azure repo this way, you need to use `<organization>:$(System.AccessToken)` as auth to git clone url.

Comment: Hi Peter, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jay's reply that you could use [Publish and download artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) instead of creating a symlink. Also yaml pipeline supports to [check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops), so you could checkout your App repository and Library repository in the same pipeline.

In addition, deleting a build that published Artifacts to a file share will result in the deletion of all Artifacts in that UNC path, so you could choose to use the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy generated artifacts to another backed up file share.

What's more, retention policies let you set how long to keep runs, releases, and tests stored in the system. To save storage space, you want to delete older runs, tests, and releases. See: [Set artifact retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-artifact-retention-policies) for details.

BTW, the url to clone Azure Git Repos containing credentials looks like: `https://{username}:{password}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/reposiotry_name`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66274678/14886002 for guidance.