# Create fork repository in Azure Devops by Powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, fork

I am writting logic that adds contant of nuget package to repository. I want to automate process of creating commits and Pull Request to original repository. Potentially it will be run in Pipeline. So, does anybody know how to create fork by powershell script?
I can create Pull Request from fork by using Rest API:

```
$pullRequestUri = "$orgUri/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
$body = @{
"sourceRefName" = "refs/heads/main"
"targetRefName" = "refs/heads/main"
"forkSource" = @{
    "repository" = @{
        "id" = $forkRepositoryId
    }
}
"title" = "Add $PackageName package"
"isDraft" = $True
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help? It shows how to run a git command inside a DevOps pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271214/how-to-run-a-git-command-from-a-pipeline-using-yaml-in-azure-devops

Comment: You can have a look of the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <PAT>")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$body = "{
`n  `"name`": `"<Dict fork repo Name>`",
`n  `"project`": {
`n    `"id`": `"<Dict Project ID>`"
`n  },
`n  `"parentRepository`": {
`n    `"name`": `"<Source repo name>`",
`n    `"id`": `"<Source repo ID>`",
`n    `"project`": {
`n      `"id`": `"<Source project ID>`"
`n    }
`n  }
`n}"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Success on my side:

[image]

How to get the projects' IDs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

How to get the repositories' IDs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0